# How to delete TFS shelvesets from the TFS plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, tfs

I have a ton of shelvesets and I wanted to delete the old ones that aren't relevant anymore. I tried to delete from the Builds tab inside of the Eclipse plugin, but that list is read-only. Is there a way to delete a TFS shelveset from Eclipse directly without having to go into Visual Studio/Visual Studio Team Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about doing this in Eclipse but there is a tool called [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm) which can be used to find and delete the TFS Shelvesets without using Visual Studio/Visual Studio Team Explorer.